# The keyboard is open again after compose AlertDialog is dismissed

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have a TextField in the AlertDialog and I want to handle the keyboard on it but When I open AlertDialog in Compose the keyboard is open. but when I click on the cancel button inside the dialog, the keyboard is closed but it opens again. how can I fix this issue?

```
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        return ComposeView(requireContext()).apply {
            setContent {
                val viewState by viewModel.state.collectAsState()
                val controller = LocalSoftwareKeyboardController.current
                val focusRequester = remember { FocusRequester() }
                val focusManager = LocalFocusManager.current
               
                val (disputeReason, updateDisputeReason) = remember {
                    mutableStateOf("")
                }
               
                val openDisputeDialog = remember {
                    mutableStateOf(false)
                }
                LaunchedEffect(key1 = openDisputeDialog.value) {
                    if (!openDisputeDialog.value) {
                        controller?.hide()
                        focusManager.clearFocus()
                    } else {
                        focusRequester.requestFocus()
                    }
                }
              
                var rating: Float by remember { mutableStateOf(1f) }
                ComposeMaterial3Theme {
                    
                    if (openDisputeDialog.value) {
                        AlertDialog(onDismissRequest = { openDisputeDialog.value = false },
                            text = {
                                Column(
                                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                                    verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(16.dp)
                                ) {
                                    CustomMultiLineTextField(
                                        modifier = Modifier
                                            .fillMaxWidth()
                                            .focusRequester(focusRequester)
                                            .heightIn(min = 140.dp, max = 300.dp),
                                        value = disputeReason,
                                        shape = MaterialTheme.shapes.medium,
                                        onValueChange = {
                                            updateDisputeReason(it)
                                        }
                                    )
                                }
                            },
                            buttons = {
                                Row(
                                    modifier = Modifier
                                        .fillMaxWidth()
                                        .padding(
                                            start = spaceMedium,
                                            end = spaceMedium,
                                            bottom = spaceMedium
                                        )
                                ) {
                                    TransparentButton(
                                        modifier = Modifier
                                            .width(spaceFree)
                                            .weight(1f)
                                            .fillMaxWidth(),
                                        toUppercase = false,
                                        title = stringResource(com.sky.res.R.string.cancel),
                                    ) {
                                        openDisputeDialog.value = false
                                    }
                                  
                                }
                            })
                    }
                    PerCaseTabScreen(
                        onOpenDisputeDialog = {
                            selectedReservedCaseToFinish.value = it
                            updateDisputeReason("")
                            openDisputeDialog.value = true
                        },
                        state = viewState,
                    ) {
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

https://filebin.net/ssjeuwfq2t2d8163

Comment: try clearing focus and hiding the keyboard before hiding the dialog.

Comment: i mean onDismissRequest

Comment: @AkashSinha not working

Comment: What is the value of the `android:windowSoftInputMode` in your manifest?

Comment: @JanItor stateHidden|adjustResize

Comment: Try removing `stateHidden`. If it works, you probably won't need `controller` and `focusManager`.

Comment: @JanItor Thanks a lot, it works. I don't need a controller anymore but still need focusManager

Comment: Nice, i should put it in the answer then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have `stateHidden` in the `android:windowSoftInputMode` attribute to the `<activity>` element in your manifest, try removing it.